# How to apply a JQuery function to all PHP elements that are dynamically created with the same name?

Tags: php, jquery

Essentially what I'm trying to do is apply a JQuery function to all of my select elements with a certain 'name' property. I've tried using the '.each()' function, to no avail. I've also tried enclosing the function call within a

```
$(function(){
    $('select[name=".."]').change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

My page starts out with a select element. Then I click a button to add another select element with the same name. Each time I change the option for these selects, I want them to disable.

So far, only the first select disables - nothing happens for the following selects that are dynamically created by PHP.

Anyone know how to handle this case?

Thanks-

Comment: can you put it into a fiddle?

Comment: Not really because the PHP uses an external repository :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `.on` with the body and the selector for dynamically generated Selects

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('change','select[name=".."]',function(){
        //do Something
    });
});
```